# Teamcity build agent in disconnected state

Tags: linux, teamcity, build-agent

I am running teamcity on Linux server, and it was working completely fine. Once I reboot the server machine and it stopped working. I managed to start the teamcity server using runAll.sh command, but the build agent stays in "disconnected" state. The inactivity reason is being shown as 'server shutdown'. I tried to start the agent using 'agent.sh stop' and 'agent.sh start' but it does not seem to work. Could not get anything meaningful from the logs.

Kindly help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found this while looking thru my unanswered questions, It was actually a permission issue. I wasn't running the commands as root user. Once I ran  'agent.sh stop' and 'agent.sh start' as a root user, it worked okay.

Answer (score 2):

Incase, if you modified the teamcity port then you'll need to change the build agent configuration files to reflect the new serverUrl value. You can find this setting in the C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\conf\buildAgent.properties file.

Comment: Thank you! I had exactly this scenario having changed my server from localhost to a specific local IP. I changed the serverUrl value in the buildAgent.properties file and restarted the service and after a minute everything clicked back into place.

Answer (score 1):

On the machine that restarted, make sure the firewall didn't come back up in a state that blocks access to/from the agent. 
When you restart the agent, the teamcity-agent.log file should have a line saying something like, "buildServer.AGENT.registration - Registering on server". If it succeeds, it should say something like "buildServer.AGENT.registration - Registered: id:.., authorizationToken:..".